# Error in Java code : Class, interface or enum expected?

Tags: java

I cannot seem to understand whats the issue with the following code. Can you please explain what changes to make? the error says following:

```
./Root/Main.java:17: error: class, interface, or enum expected
System.out.println(" "); 
^ 1 error
```

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 13 * 7 * 23;
int a = 1;
while (a <= num/2) {
    if (num%a == 0) {
        System.out.print(a + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println(" ");
```

Comment: The error I get with the code you posted is "reached end of file while parsing". Indent your code, and the incorrect structure will suddenly appear.

Comment: Use a real IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing two close braces (`"}"`) to close the method and class declarations. Add those and your code should compile.

Answer (score 0):

Are You closing the `main` function with a bracket? Because I don't see it in the code You providede.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
while (a <= num/2) {
if (num%a == 0) {
    System.out.print(" " + a);
}
```

}

Try to do the changes I made.

You should post line numbers of your code.